# How to replace nested IF/ELSE branches with SIMD (SSE or AVX)?

Tags: simd, branch-prediction, simd-library

**EDIT x 2**

- Added more comprehensive function which returns an abstract register class: the function outputs a register full of floats. I don't care the actual length - SSE, AVX... - because Google Highway will figure that out for me.
- Working code [available on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5833nG4Gj)
- `test1`, `test2`, `test3` could also be masks

**EDIT**

- Returned values are not known at compile time (these trivial values are there just to make the branching immediate to understand)
- I fixed the branching that was so immediate to understand that I got it wrong (:

---

I'm new to SIMD and I'm using Google Highway to achieve a portable (x86 and ARM) solution, so I'm writing this question in general terms.

I'm trying to speedup this C/C++ code with SIMD instructions

```c
  const bool test1 = foo(input1) > 0; // unpredictable 
  const bool test2 = foo(input2) > 0; // unpredictable 
  const bool test3 = foo(input3) > 0; // unpredictable 

  const RegisterWithFourFloats out0;  // not known at compile time
  const RegisterWithFourFloats out1;  // not known at compile time
  const RegisterWithFourFloats out12; // not known at compile time
  const RegisterWithFourFloats out13; // not known at compile time
  const RegisterWithFourFloats out123;// not known at compile time

if (test1)
  if(test2) 
    if (test3)
       return out123; 
    else
       return out12; 
  else
    if (test3)
       return out13; 
    else
       return out1; 
else 
  return out0;
```

So the keys are

| `test 1` | `test 2` | `test 3` | returned value | mask name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | `mask1` |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 123 | `mask2` |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 13 | `mask3` |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 12 | `mask4` |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | `mask5` |

I hope this question is clear and I'm very happy to improve it. I guess the solution should be a  general SIMD strategy that I can test.

I have tried two solutions that return the **correct output** but are slower:

1. Flatten the IF/ELSE cascade by removing nested IF/ELSE. This creates more jump instructions and therefore gives poor performance.
2. Go branch free with [`IfThenElse` function](https://google.github.io/highway/en/master/quick_reference.html#ternary-operator) that basically creates AND/OR masks:

```
Vec result = [test1, test2, test3]
output = IfThenElse( Xor( mask1, result), 0,   output)
output = IfThenElse( Xor( mask2, result), 123, output)
output = IfThenElse( Xor( mask3, result), 12,  output)
output = IfThenElse( Xor( mask4, result), 13,  output) 
output = IfThenElse( Xor( mask5, result), 1,   output) 

return output;
```

I took a bit of a shortcut here to keep the question concise, but the idea of The `Xor` operator is that it results in a mask with true values IFF `maskX` is block-wise equal to `result`. Therefore, the value of `output` is updated only when `maskX` is block-wise equal to `result`. The result is correct, but the runtime cost higher.

Comment: Why not just multiply the `test` values (i.e. 0 or 1) by their value (1, 2, or 3) and sum the results?

Comment: @SamMason multiply?  Hopefully you mean "mask", like `_mm_and_si128` (bitwise AND with a mask whose elements are either 0 or -1).   SIMD compares produce masks precisely to enable this kind of use.  Or AVX-512 produces bitmasks but allows using them to mask vector ops.  But anyway no, that doesn't work here.  `1+2+3` = 6, not `123`.  And since we need `13` or `12` instead of `103` or `120`, we can't just use `100`, `20` and `3` as the values.

Comment: If you have a byte-shuffle like SSSE3 `pshufb` or ARM `tbl` available, in this case instead of masking and blending many different ways, you could combine three mask vectors like `mask1 | (mask2 << 1) | (mask3 << 2)`.  If they're normal masks (all-one / all-zero bits) then maybe `pabsb` absolute value the result of combining them, and combine with addition instead of OR, since you need the high bit clear.  Then use `pshufb` as a lookup table for 16 bytes in parallel, from a table of 16 bytes.  The high bytes of each 32-bit element get zeroed since your `000` key maps to `0`.

Comment: Your source code doesn't match the table.  In the C++, both sides of the `if(test2){}else{}` are the same.  I assume the table is correct.

Comment: @PeterCordes just noticed that as well, am assuming the second 12 should be a 13?

Comment: Another way to do this branchlessly is probably less efficient since it involves multiplying by 10.  Starting with a constant `_mm_set1_epi32(1)`, `tmp = test2 ? tmp*10 + 2 : tmp;` and `tmp = test3 ? tmp*10 + 3 : tmp;`.  Then use `test1` to mask the whole thing to zero or not.  If you use an actual multiply-accumulate instruction, you could maybe use a blend to make it `tmp * 1 + 0`, but that would require blending 2 inputs instead of just blending the output.  (And x86 `_mm_blendv_epi8` costs 2 uops on Intel CPUs, at least for the AVX encoding.)

Comment: I'm not sure you will be able to get any speedup for this code, or equivalent scalar code that loads the returned value from a static array by the index composed of the test results (similar to what Peter Cordes suggested, only without involving vector instructions). This is unless you have many (tens, hundreds, thousands) of these test results. Which means that either the test results need to be precomputed, or `foo`, `bar` and `baz` need to be vectorized, and the test results are vectors instead of scalar booleans.

Comment: The pseudo-code at the top does not match the table below (please [edit] to clarify this). In the pseudo-code it would make sense to check `test3` before `test2`. Are the actual return values fixed (known at compile time or outside the critical loop)?

Comment: @SamMason forgive me, I've over-simplified my code (and screwed it up..). The returned value is not known at compile time and not so trivial. Let me fix the question

Comment: @chtz edited: returned values are not known at compile time

Comment: @AndreySemashev my question was misleading: return values are not known at compile time, and I don't have hundreds of these. Only half-dozen

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks! I do have byte-shuffle. I will however need a day to fully appreciate your answer :) I'm quite new to SIMD and I need pen and paper to figure things out ... :)

Comment: @stuckoverlow byte-shuffle (almost) only makes sense if the values are known at compile-time (and only 8 bit large). You did not clarify if the values are the same every time, or, e.g. are calculated individually for every element. Maybe add a surrounding loop to your pseudo-code -- or even better provide some actually compiling code (e.g. a function with `float *out`, `float const* in`, `size_t size` arguments).

Comment: @chtz: preparing a lookup vector for reuse by many vectorized lookups should be fine for runtime-variable values.  e.g. store 5 elements to an array, `pshufb` with a constant to copy them to all the places they need to be in a lookup table.  Costs a store-forwarding stall and a `pshufb`.  Note that the `0` for all-zero masks is still known at compile-time, so wider integers can be supported as long as the lookup values we want fit in 8 bits zero-extended.  But yeah, we do need more details from the OP like which things are loop-invariant of big-enough loops even if not compile-time fixed.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes true. `pshufb` can also be useful if calculating the LUT happens outside the critical loop.

Comment: Thanks alll! I will proved and compiling example in godbolt and improve the answer further. But prior to that, massive thanks! I’m learning a lot!

Comment: @chtz I updated the question with compiling code: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5833nG4Gj

Comment: @PeterCordes I have added a comping code and moved all the computation outside the IF/ELSE branches. I have abstracted the return type to make the question more widely applicable, but you could assume something like `__m128`.

Comment: `__m128` floats?  So you expect to have non-zero bits in every byte of a 4-byte return value.  That's an important different from your example.  Unless they're simple bit-patterns (like even powers of 2 so only the high 8 bits are non-zero, so you could `psrld xmm, 24`), that makes `pshufb` a lot harder.  You could generate control vectors for `vpermilps` for a table of 4 elements but only with 2-bit selectors, or for AVX2 `vpermps` for a table of 8 elements with 3-bit selectors.  But that's slower on some AMD, and at least higher latency on Intel since it's lane-crossing.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes I realised is a big difference and I had oversimplified my question :(

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by 2-bit selector?

Comment: In a control vector for https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermilps , only the low 2 bits of each element matter.

Comment: I googled "control vector" and I find very few results, perhaps is not extremely common, do you mean a mask? I saw in another answer you referred to shuffle as control vector, is that what you mean here?

Comment: @stuckoverlow Regarding "control vector" read the pseudo-code section of the `vpermilps` docu to which Peter linked to. Or search for `permutevar_ps` on Intel Intrisics Guide (the same pseudo code, but only the variable case).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know how to solve this with highway.

If you’re sure these branches are unpredictable, the code is on the performance-critical path, and you have measured the branches are the issue, here’s possible solutions in C++ without Highway.

The following method uses blend instructions, and requires at least SSE 4.1:

```cpp
// returns ( cond ? b : a ), without branches
inline __m128 select( __m128 a, __m128 b, bool cond )
{
    __m128i i = _mm_cvtsi32_si128( cond ? -1 : 0 );
    i = _mm_shuffle_epi32( i, _MM_SHUFFLE( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) );
    return _mm_blendv_ps( a, b, _mm_castsi128_ps( i ) );
}

__m128 select5_blend( __m128 out0, __m128 out1, __m128 out12, __m128 out13,
    __m128 out123, bool test1, bool test2, bool test3 )
{
    __m128 t0 = select( out13, out123, test2 );
    __m128 t1 = select( out1, out12, test2 );
    __m128 t = select( t1, t0, test3 );
    return select( out0, t, test1 );
}
```

NEON version:

```cpp
// returns ( cond ? b : a ), without branches
inline float32x4_t select( float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b, bool cond )
{
    uint32_t mask = cond ? ~0u : 0u;
    uint32x4_t cv = vdupq_n_u32( mask );
    return vbslq_f32( b, a, cv );
}
```

---

Here’s another method which uses stores followed by loads.
It’s easily portable to highway, but I would expect it to be slower because it loads from memory immediately after the data is stored there.

```cpp
__m128 select5_mem( __m128 out0, __m128 out1, __m128 out12, __m128 out13,
    __m128 out123, bool test1, bool test2, bool test3 )
{
    __m128 arr[ 5 ];
    arr[ 0 ] = out1;
    arr[ 1 ] = out13;
    arr[ 2 ] = out12;
    arr[ 3 ] = out123;
    arr[ 4 ] = out0;

    size_t idx = test3 ? 1 : 0;
    idx |= test2 ? 2 : 0;
    idx = test1 ? idx : 4;
    return arr[ idx ];
}
```

Comment: `_mm_cvtsi32_si128` / `_mm_shuffle_epi32(v, 0)` is just `_mm_set1_epi32()`.  Write it that way to let compilers more easily use better instructions if available, e.g. AVX-512F `vpbroadcastd xmm0, eax`.

Comment: Also, you have one scalar controlling all 4 elements of the blend?  I had been assuming we had a few different loop-invariant values and different mask values for each element, but after the last update to the question, that does look like the structure they want.  Hrm, storing to an array of `__m128` and indexing with a constant derived from the mask could be interesting, esp. on Ice Lake and later (2 stores per clock).  Critical path latency is one store-forwarding, instead of a tree of variable blends.  Oh, you had the same idea, second half of your answer!

Comment: @Soonts thanks! I believe they are both easy to port to Highway. The first should be just a different combination of IfTheElse. 
The second one also looks easy and I wonder: instead of computing all values of ‘outX’ stored in ‘arr’, could I use the cascade of if statements to select a pointer to the function that computes the only one value that will be returned? 
Hope that’s clear and I believe the answer is “depends on the cost of each one of those functions”, so yeah, I’ll give that a try :) thanks! I’ll follow this up

Comment: @stuckoverlow If the condition flags don't change inside the loop you can copy the loop inside the branches -- for simple loops that would not even significantly increase the generated binary size. gcc/clang do this when compiling with `-funswitch-loops` (enabled by `-O3`, results may vary depending on the complexity of the loop).

Comment: @chtz I'm not sure if I understand what loop you refer to. I exploited all possible coherency I could between two calls of my code snippet.

Comment: I got some results implemented in Highway. The branch free implementation suggested by @Soonts runs at 7ns, while the brancy solutions (Both my original reference snipped and the solution posted by @Soonts) vary depending on the final answer. However in the worst case scenario brancy take 7ns, in the best scenario takes only 2.3 ns. I also tried using pointer to functions as output of the IF branches of , but the runtime is identicaly.
My conclusion is that I cannot squeeze performance our of SIMD here. Perhaps I should have profiled more before embarking here, but was good learning!